# Como obter o $recipient (destinatário) dos emails Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

Estou tentando obter o email do destinatário dos emails Woocommerce que vão para o Admin. Sei que existe outras formas de fazer isso mas preciso que seja por meio do comparativo entre o destinatário e o Admim WP.

```
////////// BCC EMAIL /////////////
function bcc_email_headers( $headers ){
   $recipient = get_from_address();
   $admin = get_option('admin_email');

    if ( $recipient == $admin ){
        $headers .= 'BCC: Name <bcc@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'bcc_email_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Ou uma outra forma que me atentede, seria por meio do `order_status`. Eu tentei isso:

```
////////// BCC EMAIL by Order Status /////////////
function bcc_email_headers( $headers, $order ){
   global $woocommerce;

    if ( wc_get_order() == 'meu_status' ){
        $headers .= 'BCC: Name <bcc@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
    }
    return $headers;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'bcc_email_headers', 10, 3 );
```

Mas também não funciona